# module 'h5py' has no attribute 'File' when trying to save a tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, h5py

So I Just made a small NN with the MNIST Digit Database and I'm trying to save it. Here is the full code:

```
# Importing Libs
import h5py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras

# ---------- PART I: Importing and cleaning Data ----------
# Importing Data
train_data = np.genfromtxt('mnist_train.csv', delimiter=',')[1:]
test_data  = np.genfromtxt('mnist_test.csv', delimiter=',')[1:]

train_images = train_data[:, 1:]
train_labels = train_data[:, 0]

test_images  = test_data[:, 1:]
test_labels  = test_data[:, 0]

class_names = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

train_images = train_images/255
test_images = test_images/255

train_images = train_images.reshape(60000, 28, 28)
test_images = test_images.reshape(10000, 28, 28)

# ---------- PART II: Making the model ----------
layers = [keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)), 
          keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'), 
          keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')]

model = keras.Sequential(layers)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=1
model.save("network.h5")
```

And here is the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-0e5ebf05c427> in <module>
      1 print('Saving Model...')
----> 2 model.save("network.h5")

~\Downloads\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)
   1006     """
   1007     save.save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format,
-> 1008                     signatures, options)
   1009 
   1010   def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=True, save_format=None):

~\Downloads\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\save.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)
     97 
     98   if (save_format == 'h5' or
---> 99       (h5py is not None and isinstance(filepath, h5py.File)) or
    100       os.path.splitext(filepath)[1] in _HDF5_EXTENSIONS):
    101     # TODO(b/130258301): add utility method for detecting model type.

AttributeError: module 'h5py' has no attribute 'File'
```

My versions:

1. tensorflow: 2.1.0
2. keras: 2.2.4-tf
3. h5py: 2.10.0
4. Anaconda: 2019.10

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I don't see how the currently accepted solution is different than what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.Its working fine.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model.save("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
 
# load model
model = load_model('model.h5')
```

Comment: This seems to solve the problem, but I actually have no idea why. What does does the load_model function have to do with the model.save function?

Comment: This method was used to save and load the model using keras. If you want to use another method, you can.For further details refer this,https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a problem with versions of the different libraries. I have also faced the same problem when using TensorFlow. From the anaconda prompt, you can check which version of h5py is compatible with TensorFlow. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling many times but at last, installing a compatible version of h5py, the problem was solved. Conda prompt screenshot can be checked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsfuB.png).

Comment: you can see that the problem was solved from the accepted answer, but since you're trying to present an answer, it should be generic, and the screenshot version is not same as the given version asked in question

Answer (score 1):

I got rid on the problem by uninstalling the existing h5py, then re-install using conda.

`$ conda install h5py`

I hope it works for you too. :D

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in my environment downgrading the h5py module to 3.1.0, witch in TensorFlow 2.6 compatible.